# How to show users list in Javascript with parse JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I try to put the list of users on the page and call this list of users in JavaScript

my page:

```
<div id="all_users" data-users='{"name":"jan","userName":"user_jan"}{"name":"jack","userName":"user_jack"}{"name":"jim","userName":"user_jim"}'></div>
```

I want to call the list of users from the above code in JavaScript

```
var users = document.querySelector("#all_users");
```

How can I call the user list like this in javascript?

```
values: [
          {name: 'jan', userName: 'user_jan'},
          {name: 'jack', userName: 'jack_jan'},
          {name: 'jim', userName: 'jim_jan'},

        ],
```

update: I changed the above code from double quotes to single quotes.
and use

```
var json = JSON.parse(users.dataset.users);
console.log(json)
```

show me this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 49
```

Comment: Change the outer `"` into `'`. And try using `JSON.parse(users.dataset.user)`? (the data is invalid json btw)

Comment: You could embed JSON in your data, by using single quotes: `data-users='{"name":"jan", "userName":"user_jan"},...` and then `JSON.parse(users.dataset.users)`

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: Note that this still won't work if any of the JSON data contains single quotes. Embedding complex data like this in attributes is not a great idea.

Comment: You need square brackets around everything, and commas between each object, so that the JSON will be an array of objects.

Comment: Instead of embedding it into the HTML, why don't you just generate a `<script>` tag that creates a JavaScript object literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do the following things before to get that result:

1. Fix your data attribute "data-users" with an array of objects like this:

   `data-users='[{"name":"jan","userName":"user_jan"}, {"name":"jack","userName":"user_jack"},{"name":"jim","userName":"user_jim"}]'`
2. to get the data attribute from your querySelector users you need to use .dataset.users to select the data-users attribute.
3. Use JSON.parse to turn into an object like the following code.

```js
const users = document.querySelector("#all_users");

console.log(JSON.parse(users.dataset.users));
```

```html
<div id="all_users" data-users='[{"name":"jan","userName":"user_jan"},{"name":"jack","userName":"user_jack"},{"name":"jim","userName":"user_jim"}]'></div>
```